# Function on JavaScript won't load on php

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, button

I have a function code for showing marker, map, and route on my js file, but it won't load when I clicked on button in my php file  when there is button for call that function. Before, I group all code to one file php , the button when i clicked it's working (1 php file contain all code), but when I move it to php file which is part of the other project (website php linked to file.js and config.php) the button didn't work, Help me with this

This is my function code from javascript file :

```js
    var lat = 18.35827827454; //default latitude
    var lng = 121.63744354248; //default longitude
    var lat2 = 18.35827827454; //default latitude
    var lng2 = 121.63744354248; //default longitude
    var ren, ser;

    var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); //set default coordinates
    var homeLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2); //set default coordinates
    

    var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ //set marker
      position: homeLatlng, //set marker position equal to the default coordinates
      map: map, //set map to be used by the marker
      icon: 'seru a.png',
    });

    // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(homeMarker, i) {
    //       return function() { 
    //     var id= homeLatlng[i][0];
  
    //     $.ajax({
    //       url : "places_config.php",
    //       data : "idlokasi=" +id ,
    //       success : function(data) {
    //           infowindow.setContent(data);
    //           infowindow.open(map, homeMarker);
    //       }
    //     });
    //   }
    // })(homeMarker, i));

    var homeMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ //set marker
      position: homeLatlng2, //set marker position equal to the default coordinates
      map: map, //set map to be used by the marker
      icon: 'seru b.png',
      // draggable: true //make the marker draggable
    });


    
    //PETA AWAL
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.8707131,112.5255514), //set map center
      zoom: 14, //set zoom level to 17
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //set map type to road map
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions); //initialize the map



    //if the position of the marker changes set latitude and longitude to 
    //current position of the marker
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, 'position_changed', function(){
      var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().lat(); //set lat current latitude where the marker is plotted
      var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().lng(); //set lat current longitude where the marker is plotted
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker2, 'position_changed', function(){
      var lat2 = homeMarker2.getPosition().lat(); //set lat current latitude where the marker is plotted
      var lng2 = homeMarker2.getPosition().lng(); //set lat current longitude where the marker is plotted
    });     
    
    //if the center of the map has changed
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){
      var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().lat(); //set lat to current latitude where the marker is plotted
      var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().lng(); //set lng current latitude where the marker is plotted     
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){
      var lat2 = homeMarker2.getPosition().lat(); //set lat to current latitude where the marker is plotted
      var lng2 = homeMarker2.getPosition().lng(); //set lng current latitude where the marker is plotted
    });



    //SEARCH BY GOOGLE
    var input = document.getElementById('search_new_places'); //get element to use as input for autocomplete
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input); //set it as the input for autocomplete

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map); //bias the results to the maps viewport
    
    //executed when a place is selected from the search field
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
        
        //get information about the selected place in the autocomplete text field
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); 
        
        if (place.geometry.viewport){ //for places within the default view port (continents, countries)
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport); //set map center to the coordinates of the locationd
        } else { //for places that are not on the default view port (cities, streets)
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);  //set map center to the coordinates of the location
          map.setZoom(17); //set a custom zoom level of 17
        }

        homeMarker.setMap(map); //set the map to be used by the  marker
        homeMarker.setPosition(place.geometry.location); //plot marker into the coordinates of the location 
        homeMarker2.setMap(map); //set the map to be used by the  marker
        homeMarker2.setPosition(place.geometry.location); //plot marker into the coordinates of the location 
  
    });


  $('#plot_marker').click(function(e){ //used for plotting the marker into the map if it doesn't exist already
      e.preventDefault(); 
      homeMarker.setMap(map); //set the map to be used by marker
      // homeMarker.setPosition(map.getCenter()); //set position of marker equal to the current center of the map
      homeMarker2.setMap(map); //set the map to be used by marker
      // homeMarker2.setPosition(map.getCenter()); //set position of marker equal to the current center of the map
      map.setZoom(16);

      // window.location.reload();
      
      $('input[type=text], input[type=hidden]').val('');
  });


$('#refresh').click(function(e){
window.location.reload();
$('input[type=text], input[type=hidden]').val('');
  });


  // CARI LOKASI TERSIMPAN
  $('#search_ex_places').blur(function(){//once the user has selected an existing place
      
      var place = $(this).val();
      //initialize values
      var exists = 0;
      var lat = 0; 
      var lng = 0;
      var lat2 = 0; 
      var lng2 = 0;

      $('#saved_places option').each(function(index){ //loop through the save places
        var cur_place = $(this).data('place'); //current place description
        

        //if current place in the loop is equal to the selected place
        //then set the information to their respected fields
        if(cur_place == place){ 
          exists = 1;
          $('#place_id').val($(this).data('idlokasi'));
          lat = $(this).data('lat');
          lng = $(this).data('lng');
          lat2 = $(this).data('lat2');
          lng2 = $(this).data('lng2');
          $('#n_nama').val($(this).data('nama'));
          $('#n_description').val($(this).data('description'));
        }
      });
      
      if(exists == 0){//if the place doesn't exist then empty all the text fields and hidden fields
        $('input[type=text], input[type=hidden]').val('');
        
      }else{
        //set the coordinates of the selected place
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var position2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);
        
        //set marker position
        homeMarker.setMap(map);
        homeMarker.setPosition(position);

        homeMarker2.setMap(map);
        homeMarker2.setPosition(position2);

        //set the center of the map
        map.setCenter(homeMarker.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(17);

        map.setCenter(homeMarker2.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(17);

      ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
      ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
      });

      ser.route({
      origin: position,
      destination: position2,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        ren.setDirections(response);
        } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }      
        });


//menampilkan INFOWINDOW
            // var contentString = 
            // '<div id="content">'+
            // '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            // '</div>'+
            // '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">AKHIR</h3>'+
            // '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            // '<p>menampilkan informasi</p>'+
            // '<p>Web <a href="Facebook">'+
            // 'www.facebook.com</a> .</p>'+
            // '</div>'+
            // '</div>';
 
            // var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            //   content: contentString
            // });
 
            // google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker2, 'click', function() {
            //   infowindow.open(map,homeMarker2);
            // });      

      }
    });


    // SIMPAN LOKASI
    $('#btn_save').click(function(){
      var nama   = $.trim($('#n_nama').val());
      var description = $.trim($('#n_description').val());
      var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().lat();
      var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().lng();
      var lat2 = homeMarker2.getPosition().lat();
      var lng2 = homeMarker2.getPosition().lng();
      
      $.post('save_place.php', {'nama' : nama, 'description' : description, 'lat' : lat, 'lng' : lng, 'lat2' : lat2, 'lng2' : lng2}, 
        function(data){
          var idlokasi = data;
          var new_option = $('<option>').attr({'data-id' : idlokasi, 'data-place' : nama, 'data-lat' : lat, 'data-lng' : lng, 'data-lat2' : lat2, 'data-lng2' : lng2, 'data-description' : description}).text(place);
          new_option.appendTo($('#saved_places'));
        }
      );
      
      $('input[type=text], input[type=hidden]').val('');
    });
```

```css
#map {
  border: 1px solid #DDD; 
  width:600px;
  height: 300px;
  float:left;  
  margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #AAA 0px 0px 15px;
}

           #map img { 
  max-width: none;
}

#map label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}
```

```html
<?
require_once('places_config.php');
$places = $db->query("SELECT * FROM lokasi");
?>

<style>
#map_container{ 
  width: 630px;
  height: 330px;
  float: left;
}
#map_canvas{
  width: 95%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left:10px;
  border: 5px solid darkgrey;
}
</style>


<legend> <h3> <center> Daftar Jalur Rawan Kecelakaan </center> </h3> </legend>

<div class='row'>
  <div class="span8">


  <div id="map"></div>
</div> <!--end -f span-->
<div class="span8 ">

<div id="map_container">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>

<form   method="POST" id="form1" action="lokasi/map_view.php" class='form-horizontal'>
<br>


   <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="search_new_places">Cari Lokasi Tempat</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search New Places" id="search_new_places" autofocus>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="search_ex_places">Cari Lokasi Tersimpan</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Saved Places" id="search_ex_places" list="saved_places">
    </div>
  </div>  

<input type="hidden" name="idlokasi" id="idlokasi"/>

<center>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control"> 
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="plot_marker" value="Cari tempat"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control"> 
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh" value="Refresh"/> 
  </div>
</div>


</center>

<!-- <br>
<p>
<label for="place"><b><u>INPUT TEMPAT BARU</b></u></label>
</p>

<p>
<label for="place">Nama</label>
<input type="text" name="n_nama" id="n_nama"/>  
</p>

<p>
<label for="description">Description</label>
<input type="text" name="n_description" id="n_description"/>  
</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" id="btn_save" value="Simpan tempat"/>
</p>
</form> -->

<datalist id="saved_places">
<!--loop through the places saved in the database and store their data into each of the data attribute in the options-->  
<?php while($row = $places->fetch_object()){ ?> 
  <option value="<?php echo $row->nama; ?>" 
    data-id="<?php echo $row->idlokasi; ?>" 
    data-id="<?php echo $row->gambar; ?>"
    data-id="<?php echo $row->description; ?>"
    data-lat="<?php echo $row->lat; ?>" 
    data-lng="<?php echo $row->lng; ?>"
    data-lat2="<?php echo $row->lat2; ?>" 
    data-lng2="<?php echo $row->lng2; ?>"  
    data-place="<?php echo $row->nama; ?>" >
    <?php echo $row->nama; ?>
  </option>
<?php } ?>  
</datalist>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>

<script src="js/map.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're using jQuery, but your HTML never loads `jquery.js`. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: There is no error in Javascript module. 
I have function showing marker, function when I click the button will show marker I've saved from database to my maps, and button refresh for refreshing the page in map.js. 
How to make all of my function in map.js to be work in my html which has contain button "Find location" and "refresh" ?

Comment: I have the other one php which is function is to input marker by user to database by button and use js.file (contain function input lat lng marker saved to database) that is work, but this php why won't work like the other one?